# Get form ID on hook_entity_presave()

Tags: 8, hooks

I want to process some details before saving the node in Drupal 8. How will I get the form ID of the submitted form?

```
function mymodule_entity_presave(Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity) {
  $entity->getEntityType()->id() // this only prints "node"
}
```

Is there any other workaround?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`hook_entity_presave()` doesn't get the form ID, and this makes sense: An entity could be programmatically saved from a module or a Drush plugin without showing to the user a form to edit/create the entity.

Since you just want to know if the entity is being edited or created:

- You don't need to know the form ID
- You can use `hook_entity_presave()` or `hook_ENTITY_TYPE_presave()` with code similar to the following one

  ```
  function mymodule_entity_presave(Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity) {
    if ($entity->isNew()) {
      // The entity is being created.
    }
  }
  ```

As side note, `$entity->getEntityType()->id()` returns `'node'` as expected: You are asking to the entity object its entity type, and for nodes that is clearly `'node'`.

Answer (score 5):

To answer your question without going into the details as to why you needed it. (others have answered the solution to your original problem)

However, you can get the form_id from the request:

```
\Drupal::request()->get('form_id')
```

You should check if the variable is set in the first place and then check its value.
I had a specific case where i needed to take action on an entity save from a specific form but not on any other case.

This was the only solution i came up with.

Comment: Thanks for answering the original question, this is what I was looking for. In my case, I have a `presave` hook that performs some book-keeping, but only wanted it called if an editor actually used the proper form -- not if the entity was saved programmatically.

Answer (score 2):

Try :

```
function mymodule_entity_presave(Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity) {
    if($entity->isNew()){
    // NEW ENTITY HERE
    }
    else{
    //EDIT Entity here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that hook_entity_presave won't help you.

But you can use [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21form.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/8.2.x) on your node form and in code of the hook add one more submit function, which would be executed when the node form is submitted.

Anyway, in Drupal 7 the solution was as follows.

By the way, here is code, where one can see an example of addition of submit function

```
 function hook_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  if (isset($form['type']) && $form['type']['#value'] . '_node_settings' == $form_id) {
    $upload_enabled_types = \Drupal::config('mymodule.settings')->get('upload_enabled_types');
    $form['workflow']['upload_' . $form['type']['#value']] = array(
      '#type' => 'radios',
      '#title' => t('Attachments'),
      '#default_value' => in_array($form['type']['#value'], $upload_enabled_types) ? 1 : 0,
      '#options' => array(t('Disabled'), t('Enabled')),
    );
    // Add a custom submit handler to save the array of types back to the config file.
    $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'mymodule_upload_enabled_types_submit';
  }
}
```

Comment: i have to execute it before the node save as i said earlier . but hook_form_alter works after the node save

Comment: As the answer says, you would add a form submission handler, which would execute before the node is saved, if you add it in the right order. Passing the form ID to the form submission handler isn't difficult.